# Turning volume up through OS and software gives different results - why?

Tags: audio, windows-10, sound-card, system-sounds

I currently own an external DAC\Amp (Aune X1s), and when I turn the volume all the way up on the X1s and foobar2K, but turn it down almost to the minimum on the OS (Windows 10 64bit - education edition), I can't hear any static noise\hiss, but when I turn the volume all the way up on the OS and X1s, but turn it down in foobar2K (and also other softwares such as Winamp and Media Player) I can hear a very audible 'hiss'. How come there is a difference?
What does it say about the 'hiss', does it come from the X1s or the PC?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: to much preamp. the OS is amplifying the noise before it enters your Aune. Your Amp has better signal processing than your built-in sound card with the windows drivers, and it only gets amplified once rather than twice.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. The sound-card and amp combo is external, connected via USB to the PC. You think the problem is also with the sound-card have smaller dynamic range than the amp? (I don't think the signal ever passes through the built-in sound card)
Than why does it happen only with the OS on max and not with the software volume maxed? I don't understand the difference.

Maybe I should add that even when I pause a track with the volume maxed on the OS, I still hear the 'hiss'. What noise does it amplify then?